# Changing font size and color in Shiny R doesn't work?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I am trying to change the font size and color of a siderbarPanel with ID: `test_type` using the code below (in ui.r) and it doesn't work?

`tags$head(tags$style("#test_type{color: red;
                                 font-size: 20px;
                         font-style: italic;
                         }"
                         )
    )`

Any idea?

Comment: `sidebarPanel` doesn't have an id parameter. Do you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want to change the color and font of an input field element in the ui. You could do that as:

```
sidebarPanel(
    tags$head(tags$style(type="text/css", 
              ".test_type {color: red;
                           font-size: 20px; 
                           font-style: italic;}"
                        )
             ),
    div(class="test_type",
       textInput(inputId="ti1", label="Text Input 1", value = "test"))
)
```

But if you are looking to customize the sidebarPanel itself, then do check

[R shiny - background of sidebar panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891362/r-shiny-background-of-sidebar-panel)