# grouping input widgets in Shiny

Tags: r, user-interface, layout, shiny

I'm building a Shiny app and I'd like to be able to group input widgets, preferably with a title for each group. For example, I'd like a box for "Pants size" with a drop-down for waist and a drop-down for inseam, and then another box for "T-shirt size" with a drop-down for XS/S/M/L/XL and radio buttons for unisex/women's.

Is there a way to put sets of widgets in their own boxes, or to break up the standard grey box they all come in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you want to use the `fluidPage` layout and your question is only layout-related: My idea would be to "group" those widgets in panels and then to customize the style (CSS) of those panels. You can use the grid layout or the sidebar layout for example.

Example taken [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33891534/2381339).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML('
         #sidebar, #sidebar2 {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        body, label, input, button, select { 
          font-family: "Arial";
        }')
  )),
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(width = 12, id="sidebar",
                          h5("Pants size"),
                          sliderInput("waist",
                                      "waist:",
                                      min = 1,
                                      max = 50,
                                      value = 30),
                          sliderInput("inseam",
                                      "inseam:",
                                      min = 1,
                                      max = 50,
                                      value = 30)
             ),
             mainPanel( width = 0)
           )
           ),
    column(8,sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(width = 12, id="sidebar2",
                   h5("T-shirt size"),
                   selectInput("waist",
                               "Choose your size:",
                               choices = c("XS","S","M","L","XL")),
                   radioButtons("sex",
                                "sex:",
                                choices = c("unisex","women's"))
      ),
      mainPanel( width = 0)
    ) )
  )
  )
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
})
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

[image]

In this example, the critical panels have two IDs called `sidebar` and `sidebar2`. This IDs are used in the CSS section above. Read more about panels here:

- http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson2/
- http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html

Another way to use boxes is shinydashboards, read more about that here: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#boxes

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to go with shinydashboards since I want a lot of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `wellPanel()` to group inputs together, then customize the css