# How to specify the width of a sidebarPanel in pixels?

Tags: css, r, shiny

How to specify the width of a `sidebarPanel`in pixels? The `width` argument is not accurate enough in my case.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 5), # This is not accurate enough!
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also specify the `width` as a function of the percentage, `100%` = full width instead of hard-coding it to `px`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    div(style="width: 70%;",sidebarPanel(width = 5)), # This is not accurate enough!
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of [R shiny - background of sidebar panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891362/r-shiny-background-of-sidebar-panel) I found the following solution:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('#sidebar {width: 100px;}'))),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(id = "sidebar"),
    mainPanel()))

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This one does not affect other `wellPanels`.